# Binding a padding value to a DoubleProperty

Tags: javafx, properties, padding, observable

In a JavaFX application, I'm trying to set a padding value to a VBox. I wrote that code :

```
vBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
```

But with that code, I have a 10px "fixed" value for my vBox padding. Instead of that result, I'd like to link that value to a percentage of the scene size, even when I'm resizing.
I succeed to get the DoubleProperty of my scene size, but how to link it with the padding value ?
I think my code may start by :

```
vBox.paddingProperty().bind(observable);
```

but I fail to cast my DoubleProperty in a kind of "observable" object for the padding.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Bindings.createObjectBinding()` method to create custom object binding and then create `Insets` depending on your percentage `DoubleProperty`.

```
vBox.paddingProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> new Insets(percentage.doubleValue()), percentage));
```

Comment: Great, it works. And it's easier than the other solution that I had : widthProperty.addListener((ChangeListener<Object>) (arg0, arg1, arg2)
    -> vBox.setPadding(new Insets((Double)(arg2)*0.01)));